# Replace end of line with comma and put parenthesis in sed/awk

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

I am trying to process the contents of a file from this format:

```
this1,EUR 
that2,USD
other3,GBP
```

to this format:

```
this1(EUR),that2(USD),other3(GBP)
```

The result should be a single line.

As of now I have come up with this circuit of commands that works fine:

```
cat myfile | sed -e 's/,/\(/g' | sed -e 's/$/\)/g' | tr '\n' , | awk '{print substr($0, 0, length($0)- 1)}'
```

Is there a simpler way to do the same by just an awk command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{ printf "%s%s(%s)", c, $1, $2; c = ","} END { print ""}' file
```

1(EUR),2(USD),3(GBP)

Comment: This solution is super readable but it is based on the assumption that the first field is always a number. I will ammend the example to make it more general.

Comment: Indeed! Edited to work with alphanumeric first field.

Comment: I find this the simplest and more readable soltion. You can ammend the result with the new data. Thanks!

Comment: ^1 Only difference in the answer I was going to post is your `c = ","` vs my `c=FS`.

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F, '{val=val?val OFS $1"("$2")":$1"("$2")"} END{print val}' OFS=,  Input_file
```

Comment: could you please explain what is the val=val?val part ?

Answer (score 2):

Toying around with separators and `gsub`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS=")\n"}{gsub(/,/,"(");gsub(/\n/,"),")}1' file
this1(EUR),that2(USD),other3(GBP)
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    RS=""            # record ends in an empty line, not newline
    ORS=")\n"        # the last )
}
{
    gsub(/,/,"(")    # replace commas with (
    gsub(/\n/,"),")  # and newlines with ),
}1' file             # output
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `paste+sed`

```
$ # paste -s will combine all input lines to single line
$ seq 3 | paste -sd,
1,2,3

$ paste -sd, ip.txt
this1,EUR,that2,USD,other3,GBP
$ # post processing to get desired format
$ paste -sd, ip.txt | sed -E 's/,([^,]*)(,?)/(\1)\2/g'
this1(EUR),that2(USD),other3(GBP)
```